# iOS: how to customize the view for dial pop

Tags: swift5

I want to show something when the dial pop up view shown like the screen capture, please how can I do with Swift?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite get that question but if you wanna do something when you keyboard pops up you can do it in searchBarTextDidBeginEditing() which is an delegate method for UISearchBar
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate/1624303-searchbartextdidbeginediting
if you wanna know more about custom UIAlert than refer this YouTube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6TpJrZNuPU
if You wanna present something when your actionSheet is presented than you can directly add the animation programmatically after presenting the Alert
for example I presented a view after presenting an UIAlerActionSheet

```
self.present(alert, animated: true)

                    let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
                    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                    view.addSubview(view1)
```

here view1 is presented and when needed you can remove that view1 from its superView so that it will vanish

```
view1.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact the AlertController is pop by ios when i call UIApplication.shared.open(url) to dial a phone. I can present a viewcontroller (e.g. vc1) before call open(url) but I don’t know how to dismiss vc1 after click any item on AlertController.

Comment: AppDelegate. applicationDidBecomeActive is the one i am looking for!

Comment: ooh I am not sure if this will work but still try it , when you click any button on that action sheet it's block of code is executed right , so at that time you can dismiss the viewController by using the dismiss method , just try it

Comment: Yes it is working well in this way. Thank you very much.

Comment: well this was my first question answering on stack overflow , happy to help ,you can tick the above answer if it worked for you ,